# R keep rows with least nas for duplicated rows

Tags: r, duplicates, filtering, dplyr

I have a data.frame containing user info but each user ID may or may not have duplicated rows with quite some missing data in different variables.
What i am trying to do is to remove duplicated user data, but for each user, i would like to keep the row that containing least missing values in the row to retain as much as information of the user as possible. Here is an example of code to create the demo data frame. Any help would be appreciated especially if it is accomplished via "dplyr" package.

```
User_Table <- data.frame(User_ID =rep(c("UserA","UserB","UserC"),each=3),
                     VariableA= rep(c(1,NA,2),each=3),
                     VariableB = rep(c("TypeA","TypeB",NA),each=3),
                     VariableC = rep(c(NA,2,3),each=3))

User_Table[c(1,2,4,5,6,7),3] <- NA
```

Comment: For User_ID "B" and "C" there are multiple cases where the rows have minimum NAs.  Do you want to select the first case or all those rows.

Answer (score 4):

This is an approach with `dplyr`:

```
User_Table %>%
  arrange(rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%        # sort rows by number of NAs
  distinct(User_ID, .keep_all = TRUE)   # keep first row per User_ID only
```

The result:

```
  User_ID VariableA VariableB VariableC
1   UserA         1     TypeA        NA
2   UserC         2      <NA>         3
3   UserB        NA      <NA>         2
```

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for the quick reply. Because i am familiar with dplyr so i can easily understand the logic behind your code. Just a further question, what does the dots in is.na(.) and .keep_all mean respectively? Thanks again

Comment: @FelixZhao The `.` represents the data frame `User_Table`. For the `%>%` operator, the `.` always represents the left argument. The argument `.keep_all = TRUE` in `distinct` is necessary to select *all* columns.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that helps a lot, Sven

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(User_Table)[User_Table[, .I[which.min(Reduce(`+`, 
            lapply(.SD, is.na)))], User_ID]$V1]
#   User_ID VariableA VariableB VariableC
#1:   UserA         1     TypeA        NA
#2:   UserB        NA        NA         2
#3:   UserC         2        NA         3
```